# Validating the value of a ref argument using moq

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I'm struggling to figure out how I can verify that a method call was invoked with a ref argument of a particular value. The issue is I need to interact with a COM interface, so I am mocking out the COM library in my tests and many methods contain ref arguments.

The problem appears to be that the method I am testing creates the ref values and is not an argument therefore, I do not create the value being passed by ref in my test method. Many examples of handling ref arguments using moq are when the method directly being tested use ref which is not the case. Also this COM API requires the array be passed by ref, but is not modifying the value, therefore, I have no need to pass the argument to the caller.

```cs
public static int MyMethodToTest(COMLibrary lib, MyObject obj)
{
    var values = obj.ToArray();
    return lib.Function(ref values);
}

[Fact]
public void MyTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var comLib = new Mock<COMLibrary>();
    _ = comLib.Setup(f => f.Function(ref It.Ref<double[]>.IsAny)).Returns(0);

    var obj = MyObject();

    // Act
    MyMethodToTest(obj);

    // Assert (Fails!)
    comLib.Verify(f => f.Function(ref It.Ref<double[]>.IsAny), Times.Once);
}
```

I've found that I can iterate over the Invocations and corresponding arguments and validate the arguments by value comparison which is what I'm trying to achieve with verify. As an example.

```cs
comLib.Invocations.Count.Should().Be(1)  //True
comLib.Invocations[0].Arguments[0].Should().BeEquivalentTo(obj.ToArray());  //True
```

But this feels messy...